# Powershell not counting all users in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

We have about 9400 user objects in Active Directory. We are trying to come up with a powershell script to weed out the user accounts who have not logged into their accounts for the last year.

In this particular OU we have 494 disabled users. I have created this script to search for and output the number of users that are disabled. Running this gives me the output of `10`.

Going through and manually checking some users I can see that there are well above 10 users that have not logged in in over a year. Why would this not be counting them all?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$DaysInactive = 365
$InactiveDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-($DaysInactive))

$Users =Get-ADUser -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "ou=staff,ou=disabled,dc=VALPARAISO,dc=LOCAL" -Filter "LastLogonDate -lt '$InactiveDate'"

Write-Output $Users.Count;
```

Comment: Why are you setting `SearchScope` to `OneLevel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Get-ADUser` for this.  `Search-ADAccount` already does it:

```
$DaysInactive = New-TimeSpan -Days 365
$Users = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan $DaysInactive -UsersOnly -SearchBase 'ou=staff,ou=disabled,dc=VALPARAISO,dc=LOCAL'
$Users.Count
```